# Multiple Monitors not being detected in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a gaming machine and had 3 monitors on a WIN7 machine. Moving to Windows 10, None of the monitors were being detected in the settings>Display settings and could not be identified. So I've switched back to WIN7 quite smoothly.

Is there a way to prep the machine before upgrading to WIN10 ?

Also do I need to stop drivers from being updated ? Or re-plug and unplug Monitors before upgrading ?

BTW. I have 2 monitors connected via DVI to my NVIDIA gaming card. Works fine with WIN7

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try replugging the monitors after upgrading? I would have done that before rolling back just to test.

Comment: I am going to try this the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same issue on my two displays when moving to Windows 10. Here's how I resolved the problem:

- Uninstalled old Nvidia drivers using Driver Sweeper
- Underneath 'Device Manager', search for your video device, right click, and choose 'Update Device Driver Software' and then have Windows detect it automatically.

If Windows fails to find the software OR fails to install it

- Go directly to Nvidia's driver site and download the appropriate driver and run it 'As Administrator'

OR

- Try downloading their 'Gefore Experience' utility
  and have that detect and install the correct driver.

Restart, then plug in your monitors and try to detect them.